# Using SVN along with WAMP

Tags: project-management, project, apache, svn

I would like to run SVN server on my local machine along with WAMP. 
All SVN server binaries include Apache. Whereas I don't need Apache as I'm already running WAMP.

Please let me know if there are any installs available that includes only the SVN server.
If there are none available, shall I go ahead with what's available? And how would I do that without breaking anything.

PS: I tried CollabNet and VisualSVNServer. Both includes Apache.

Comment: If you're only using SVN locally, you don't need any HTTP server for it, you can simply access the repo through the filesystem.

Comment: Actually, I would like to host SVN server so that developers could start and collaborate projects on my machine. I mean, I like to create something like sourceforge.net in a small scale(not for public access).

Comment: Or... you could use distributed version control. Then you wouldn't need to deal with all of that SVN [truncated message]

Comment: Does svnserve not work?

Answer (score 1):

SVN is a module and you could be able to include it in your existing apache. I have never done this. How to do this should be part of the svn documentation.

If you're only develop on this machine, you could also use the file:// protocol and wouldn't need to integrate with apache.

**Update:**

[httpd, the Apache HTTP server](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/de/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) is the chapter from the SVN book containing information about hosting svn repositories with apache.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll check command-line binaries of SVN, you'll find svnserve, which can handle repos over net with svn:// protocol.

Or you can integrate needed parts of VisualSVN Server's config into your Apache and get http-served repos (which *in common* work better)

Comment: http served repos doesn't work better but there are some features like logging, user authentication (SSPI) which are only possible with http, sometimes svn served repos are better (performance)

Comment: Firewalled corporate environment tells me another thing

Comment: @sdu: Admin experience tells me - "Less services is better than more". PM experience tells me - "Web-frontend to repo is cool". Security experience tells me - httpS in more bullet-proof, than svn. Anyway - tastes can differ.

Comment: if there is enterprise server there would be no discussion about http-served svn - but on a local machine?